# running systemctl via ssh without asking for password

Tags: ssh, sudo, password, services, syslinux

I want to run ssh without asking for password and invoke systemctl without password
i tried doing the following:

```
ssh -t <user>@<host> "echo <password> | sudo -S systemctl status kubelet"
```

and:

```
sshpass -p '$<password>' ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' <user>@<host> 'sudo service kubelet restart
```

also:

```
 echo <password> | ssh -tt <user>@<host> "sudo service kubelet restart"
```

i added the user to the sudoers and i am able to run systemctl without password
all the commands from above ask for a password except:

```
sshpass -p '$<password>' ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' <user>@<host> 'sudo service kubelet restart
```

which gives me no prompt and looks like it worked but did nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. I am happy that you found a solution to your problem. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title and the solution inside your question. Use the **Answer Your Own Question** button below for the answer. Then after waiting for 2 days, accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used python3 for this solution, and tho not elegant but it works(this is not the full script but only the relevant part).

```py
initiate_restart = [
    "echo <password> | sudo -S systemctl restart kubelet",
    "echo <password> | sudo -S systemctl restart docker",
]
node = paramiko.SSHClient()
print(node)
node.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    node.connect(hostname=get_ip, username=user_name, password=node_pass)
    with open("/tmp/reset_log.log", "a") as f:
        f.write(date + ' Restarting ' + 'Node-' + get_ip + "\n")
except:
    print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
    with open("/tmp/reset_log.log", "a") as f:
        f.write(date + ' Could not connect to' + ' Node-' + get_ip + "\n")
    exit()
for command in initiate_restart:
    print("="*50, command, "="*50)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = node.exec_command(command)
    print(stdout.read().decode())
    err = stderr.read().decode()
    if err:
        print(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

sshpass only passes password for your ssh connection. But your "sudo service kubelet restart" - command itself asks for sudo password separately. Your systemctl status command does not need sudo privilege, that's why it goes through.
Try it like this:

```
sshpass -p '$<password>' ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' <user>@<host> "echo <password> | sudo -S service kubelet restart"
```

Comment: Still not working, I did systemctl stop kubelet and tried to execute the command above from a remote machine, it looks like it did something but the service is still stopped.
I did find a solution to the problem yesterday but I don't like it, it's adding the ssh pub key of the user to the remote system so that I could ssh without a password and add the user to the sudoers. but this is way too complicated for something that seems too simple

Comment: Can you run the "history" command on your remote machine and see what command actually got executed after running the sshpass command?

Comment: yes i checked that, found nothing, the command didn't pass any commands to the remote server